# Basic policy gradient implementation question in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to understand the code in https://github.com/openai/spinningup/blob/master/spinup/examples/pytorch/pg_math/1_simple_pg.py which implements most basic form of policy gradient. Specifically it implements the equation shown at 10.09 in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKbX1Zvo7r8&list=PLwRJQ4m4UJjNymuBM9RdmB3Z9N5-0IlY0&index=4.

In 1_simple_pg.py we pass the states and actions of the whole batch to the function compute_loss. The loss we must calculate should be of the form:

```
    u = 0;
    for each trail {  
         u += P(trail | Theta) * R(trail)
    } 
    loss = u / #of trails
```

However what it calculates inside compute_loss seem to be something else:

```
    for each item in the batch {
        x = P(a|s) * R(trail)
    }
    loss = X / #of items in the batch
```

I am new to this and also to pytorch, so my understanding above may not be correct.

Could some one clarify above please?

Thanks